# Using pandas.DataFrame.values while getting a different context?

Tags: python, pandas

I got a dataframe like

```
               rectime
0  2018-10-13 00:15:00
1  2018-10-13 00:30:00
2  2018-10-13 00:45:00
3  2018-10-13 01:00:00
```

The format of 'rectime' is `datetime`.I'd like to translate it to a list by using

```
pandas.DataFrame.values
```

What it returns is something like this

```
[['2018-10-13T00:15:00.000000000']
 ['2018-10-13T00:30:00.000000000']
 ['2018-10-13T00:45:00.000000000']
 ['2018-10-13T01:00:00.000000000']]
```

Someone can tell me why there is a difference? And how can I get the list with the same context in 'rectime'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df.rectime.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").values

array(['2018-10-13 00:15:00', '2018-10-13 00:30:00', '2018-10-13 00:45:00',
       '2018-10-13 01:00:00'], dtype=object)
```

Explanation: Pandas stores the datetime objects internally in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, but it renders date strings in a more readable format when you're interacting with printed output.
When you convert out of Pandas into a list with `.values`, you lose the pretty-print feature, and you get the full 8601 string.
You can use the `dt.strftime` method to determine exactly how you want the string representation to look, *then* move it into a list using `.values`.

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rectime': {
    0: pd.Timestamp('2018-10-13 00:15:00'),
    1: pd.Timestamp('2018-10-13 00:30:00'),
    2: pd.Timestamp('2018-10-13 00:45:00'),
    3: pd.Timestamp('2018-10-13 01:00:00')}})
```